# Unity3d: No Drag&Drop has been setup

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

I was working on a Unity 2D game project on OS X 10.10, and I can't drag file or folder, it will show this error.

```
No Drag&Drop has been setup. Please
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

I have tried:

1. save project and then restart
2. click `Assets` folder and choose `Reimport All`

But it seems not work, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you referring to moving files/folders in the Project tab under Assets?

Comment: Looks like a Unity bug, have you tried another/newer Unity Version or Patch Release?

Comment: I am referring every action using drag, like move project folder to another folder, move project object to scene. I think I should upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity uses NSPasteboard (OSX shared manager for clipboard) to hold the data for Drag&Drop, so any process that monitors/modifies the clipboard may be messing with the Drag&Drop.

I think there might be a Chrome extension that would be generating notifications that would for some reason break drag and drop. **Disable all your extensions in google chrome** and if that doesn't solve your problem in Unity then do a fresh install of google chrome.

Edit: As suggested by other users, another solution that might work is

> Quit Unity and force quit the **pboard** process via **Activity Monitor** and
>   then launch Unity again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this solution, I delete Chrome and restart Unity, but it didn't work.

Comment: I restart macbook and disable chrome extension `push bullet`, and it work. Thanks!

Comment: Ignore this answer and read Sinyo's answer below (or hopefully will be above someday)

Answer (score 10):

Recently I have the same problem and what I did was quit Unity and force quit the **pboard** process via **Activity Monitor** and then launch Unity again, it works for me.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: Worked for me, too. In case anyone was wondering about the **why**, check [this more-in-depth explanation](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/the-cut-copy-paste-daemon-in-os-x/). :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Save me from this weird problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided by [Sinyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5645500/sinyo) I created a small shell script to speed up the process and thought I would share.  [For Mac only]  It closes Unity, kills the pboard process, then reopens Unity.

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript -e 'quit app "Unity"'

pid=$(ps -fe | grep 'pboard' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
    kill $pid
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
osascript -e 'launch the application "Unity"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I might contribute. I was having the "No Drag&Drop" error in an implementation of a property drawer and tried all the tips given here with no success. I was about to give up and blame it on unity, but then I found a solution. You see, I was setting the object references and calling the `DragAndDrop.SetGenericData()` method during the mouseDown event. 
I changed it so that in the MouseDrag event I check to see if there is existing DragAndDrop (checking for null in the return of `DragAndDrop.GetGenericData()`). If its null, I set the data during on MouseDrag just before calling `DragAndDrop.StartDrag()`. 
This fixed the problem. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@user3130047](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3130047/user3130047)'s answer, this is another version. Mac Only.

1. Quit Unity.
2. In console, put this command and execute it.
   `ps aux | grep pboard | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 | launchctl start com.apple.pboard`
3. Open Unity.

That's it. 


But, this may cause your another opened applications copy&paste doesn't work. So, you need to restart them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to accomplish the best answer:

```
killall -HUP pboard
```

(from terminal or similar, obviously)